# Postconstruct not being called by ApplicationScoped bean being injected into a Singleton bean

Tags: cdi, jboss-weld, weld

Basically I want to retrieve some properties with my timer but I keep getting a null pointer because properties bean never seems to call @postconstruct. Any ideas why?

**DataCaptureTimer.java:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;


@ApplicationScoped
@Startup
public class DataCaptureTimer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Inject
    private DataCaptureBP dataCaptureBP;

    @Inject
    private transient Logger logger;

    @Inject
    private PropertiesBean propertiesBean;


    private File dataAnalyticsDirectory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUpDataCaptureTimer(){
    }


    @Schedule(hour = "18", minute = "24")
    public void automaticProcessing() {
        if(logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("Calling DataCapture");
        }

        dataAnalyticsDirectory = new File(propertiesBean.getProperty("gen.data.analytics.directory"));


        }

    }

}
```

**Properties bean**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


@ApplicationScoped
public class PropertiesBean {

    private static final String SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_NAME = "system.properties";

    private Properties props = new Properties();

    public PropertiesBean(){
    }

    /**
     * Loads all the properties from an external props file
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void initiateProperties(){
        String loc = System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.dir") + "/" + SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_NAME;
        try {
            props.load(new FileInputStream(loc));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves different system properties by a given key
     * @param key Key to desired system property
     * @return String the value of the property with a matching key
     */
    public String getProperty(String key){
        return props.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
09:19:34,617 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 5) JBAS014122: Error during retrying timeout for timer: [id=fd2f6756-8621-4977-9b65-c4110c79a149 timedObjectId=epcfe-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.epcfe-web-
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.DataCaptureTimer auto-timer?:true persistent?:true timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@70ceb77f initialExpiration=Tue Aug 14 09:19:00 EDT 2012 intervalDuration(
in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Wed Aug 15 09:19:00 EDT 2012 timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:165) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.TimerCMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(TimerCMTTxInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:229) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:303) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:189) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Fin
al-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:42) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:102) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.retryTimeout(TimerTask.java:184) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:140) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA-redhat-1.jar:2.0.0.GA-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:222) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at com.advancestores.storechannel.catalog.presentation.timer.DataCaptureTimer.automaticProcessing(DataCaptureTimer.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.F
inal-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:129) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:139) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:34) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:34) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:104) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-r
edhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:94) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final
-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:227) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
```

Comment: What happens if you put them both as @Startup? My guess is your PropertiesBean isn't actually being created at the same time as the DataCaptureTimer bean.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `PropertiesBean` - well, you are never assigning the actual properties you are reading. But as `properties` is initalized with `new Properties()`, it should never throw a NPE.

Can you post the actual stacktrace?

Also, even though this would directly answer your question. You'd get property- / resource-injection for free if you use [Seam Solder](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/3.1.0.Final/reference/en-US/html/solder-resourceloading.html). Might be worth a look...